# Converting Metafile image to byte array without System.Drawing

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, system.drawing

I need to convert a wmf file to a byte array without using System.Drawing.  The reason I can't use System.Drawing, is that some functionality of the GDI+ are not supported in an Azure environment.  The code will execute in a local environment fine, but won't work when deployed to the server.  I had to move the resize logic outside of our application to an Azure VM in order to utilize the GDI+.  We have to support wmf files for legacy applications.

The following will fail when deployed to an Azure web app.

```
byte[] imgArr;
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    sourceImage.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
    imgArr = ms.ToArray();
}
```

and

```
var imgCon = new ImageConverter();
var imgArr = (byte[])imgCon.ConvertTo(sourceImage, typeof(byte[]));
```

Both utilize the System.Drawing library and that utilizes the GDI+.  Are there any other ways to get a Windows Metafile to a byte array?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a try to use the following code, it works on my side.

```
   FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(path); // the path should be accessed in the azure portal

   // The byte[] to save the imgArr in
   byte[] imgArr= new byte[fileInfo.Length];

   // Load a filestream and put its content into the byte[]

   using (FileStream fs = fileInfo.OpenRead())
   {
       fs.Read(imgArr, 0, imgArr.Length);
   }
```